# External function call returns Top-level JSON object must contain "data" JSON array element error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a use case to utilize external functions.

Followed the steps in [External Function Sample](https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/sfguide-external-functions-examples)

Created the same function in the above GitHub repo, I was able to test the lambda function stand alone and from API on AWS, but when I call the external function from Snowflake it returns this error

Error parsing JSON response for external function EXT_FUNC_TEST with request batch id: 1234. Error: top-level JSON object must contain "data" JSON array element

Update: Here is the test payload input and response in lambda

input

`{"body": "{ \"data\": [ [ 0, 1 ], [ 1, 5], [2, \"a string\" ] ] }"}`

response

`{"statusCode": 200, "body": "{\"data\": [[0, 4], [1, 8], [2, \"Error processing this row...\"]]}"}`

Snowflake call `select Ext_Func_test(3)` generates input in CloudWatch as

`{"data": [[0, 3]]}`

how to incorporate `body` in to the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snowflake expects the response to be in a particular format.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-general.html#data-format-sent-by-snowflake

Something like:

```
{
    "data":
        [
            [ 0, 1995 ],
            [ 1, 1974 ],
            [ 2, 1983 ],
            [ 3, 2001 ]
        ]
}
```

Does the response look like the above example when you test your lambda from AWS API?

Comment: yes with test payload. updated the question with more info

Comment: I think you are not using lambda proxy integration. That is why you do not see the body element in the request. Can you check if Lambda Proxy Integration is checked in API?

Comment: you are right, that was the missing part, thank you.